# Continue animation where ended

Tags: javascript, css, animation, random, onclick

I have a 3D cube that completes one of 2 animations depending on what number is selected by math.random. The animation holds its end position after it has ended (due to "forwards") but if the cube is clicked, to run the animation again, it returns back to its original position. How to I make the cube complete the animation starting from the last time's ending position?

```
.scene {
                perspective:200px;
                width:100px;
                height:100px;
            }
            .die {
                position:relative;
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
                transform-style:preserve-3d;
                transform: translateZ(-50px);
                transition: transform 1s;
                animation:;
            }
            .face {
                position:absolute;
                width:100px;
                height:100px;
                color:white;
                top:0;
                bottom:0;
                left:0;
                right:0;
                background-color:purple;
            }
 .one {               
                transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(50px);
            }
            .two {
                transform:rotateY(90deg) translateZ(50px);
            }
             .three {
                transform:rotateY(180deg) translateZ(50px);
            }
            .four {
                transform:rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(50px);
            }
            .five {
                transform:rotateX(90deg) translateZ(50px);
            }
            .six {
                transform:rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(50px);
            }
            @keyframes one {
                0% {transform: translateZ(-5em) rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg);}
                100% {transform: translateZ(-5em) rotateY(0deg) rotateX(360deg);}
            }
            @keyframes two {
                0% {transform: translateZ(-5em) rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg);}
                100% {transform: translateZ(-5em) rotateY(-90deg) rotateX(360deg);}
            }
```

```
 <div class="scene">
        <div class="die" id="die" onclick="spinDie()">
            <div class="face one">one
            </div>
            <div class="face two">two
            </div>
            <div class="face three">three
            </div>
            <div class="face four">four
            </div>
            <div class="face five">five
            </div>
            <div class="face six">six
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        </div>
```

```
function spinDie() {
                var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1) + 1;
                if (num === 1) {
                   document.getElementById("die").style.animation="one 2s forwards"
                }
                if(num === 2) {
                    document.getElementById("die").style.animation="two 2s forwards"
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use `transition` instead of `animation`.
- Define the transitions inside an Array `faces`
- Get a random face `{x: N, y: N}`
- Addup `+=` spins to the current random face `x` and `y` valuex. I.e: `x += (360 * randomBetween(n, N))`

```js
const EL_dice = document.getElementById("dice");

// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice
const faces = [
  {x:0,   y:0},   // 1 front
  {x:0,   y:-90}, // 2 right
  {x:-90, y:0},   // 3 top
  {x:90,  y:0},   // 4 bottom
  {x:0,   y:90},  // 5 left
  {x:0,   y:180}, // 6 back
];

function spinDice() {
  const rand = ~~(Math.random() * 6); // Generate random 0 to 5
  const face = faces[rand];           // Get random face
  face.x += 360 * (~~(Math.random() * 4) + 1); // Addup some x spins
  face.y += 360 * (~~(Math.random() * 4) + 1); // Addup some y spins
  console.clear(); console.log(rand + 1);
  EL_dice.style.cssText = `
    transition: 3s cubic-bezier(0.2, -0.2, 0.5, 1.1);
    transform: rotateX(${face.x}deg) rotateY(${face.y}deg);
  `;
}

EL_dice.addEventListener("click", spinDice);
```

```css
.dice-perspective {
  display: inline-flex;
  perspective: 500px;
  margin: 20px;
  user-select: none;
}

.dice {
  --size: 80px; /* SET HERE THE DESIRED DICE SIZE */
  --half: calc(var(--size) / 2);
  width: var(--size); height: var(--size);
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.dice>div {
  height: inherit; width: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  background: #0bf; color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(var(--size) * 1.4);
  line-height: 0;
}

.front  {transform: rotateY(0deg)   translateZ(var(--half));}
.right  {transform: rotateY(90deg)  translateZ(var(--half));}
.top    {transform: rotateX(90deg)  translateZ(var(--half));}
.bottom {transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(var(--half));}
.left   {transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(var(--half));}
.back   {transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(var(--half));}
```

```html
Click dice to spin
<div class="dice-perspective">
  <div id="dice" class="dice">
    <div class="front">&#x2680;</div>
    <div class="right">&#x2681;</div>
    <div class="top">&#x2682;</div>
    <div class="bottom">&#x2683;</div>
    <div class="left">&#x2684;</div>
    <div class="back">&#x2685;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```